# How to get for each node the sum of the edge weights for children in a networkx tree

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

In the example below, how to get the sum of all the children edges from the ROOT.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node("ROOT")
for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i, weight=(i+1))
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i, weight=(2*i+1))
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i, weight=(3*i+1))

from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, arrows=True)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

For example in the example below, I would like to have for every node:

- Grandchild_4 = 13
- Child_4 = 22
- GrandChild_3 = 10
- Child_3 = 17
- ...
- ROOT = `sum of all the edges on this graph`

[image]

EDIT: here is an example which works in the accepted solution, but not the other one:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node("ROOT")
s = 0
for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("C_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("GC_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("GGC_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("GGD_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "C_%i" % i, weight=(i+1))
    s += i+1
    G.add_edge("C_%i" % i, "GC_%i" % i, weight=(2*i+1))
    s += 2*i+1
    G.add_edge("GC_%i" % i, "GGC_%i" % i, weight=(3*i+1))
    s += 3*i+1
    G.add_edge("GC_%i" % i, "GGD_%i" % i, weight=(4 * i + 1))
    s +=4 * i + 1

print(s)

from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, arrows=True)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
# plt.show()

###
leaves = {n for n in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(n)==0}

out = {}

for n in leaves:
    for parent, child in reversed(next(nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, 'ROOT', n))):
        out[parent] = (out.get(parent, 0) + out.get(child, 0)
                       + G.get_edge_data(parent, child)['weight']
                      )
from pprint import pp
pp(out)


data = {
    node: sum(G.edges[edge]["weight"] for edge in nx.bfs_edges(G, node))
    for node in G.nodes
}

from pprint import pp
pp(data)
```

Comment: I realized my initial output was not exactly yours, I updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a method that can work for any starting node, you can use an iterative process using [`bfs_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_edges.html) for example:

```py
total_weights = sum(G.edges[edge]["weight"] for edge in nx.bfs_edges(G, source))
```

You then need to iterate over each of the nodes to have what you want. As a dictionary, this would be:

```py
data = {
    node: sum(G.edges[edge]["weight"] for edge in nx.bfs_edges(G, node))
    for node in G.nodes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get find the leaves, loop over them to get the simple paths with [`all_simple_edge_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_edge_paths.html):

```
leaves = {n for n in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(n)==0}

out = {n: sum(G.get_edge_data(*e)['weight']
              for e in next(nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, 'ROOT', n)))
       for n in leaves}
```

Output:

```
{'Greatgrandchild_1': 9,
 'Greatgrandchild_0': 3,
 'Greatgrandchild_4': 27,
 'Greatgrandchild_2': 15,
 'Greatgrandchild_3': 21}
```

---

Edit: I realize my initial answer is not exactly what you want, here is a modification with the same underlying logic:

```
leaves = {n for n in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(n)==0}

out = {}

for n in leaves:
    for parent, child in reversed(next(nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, 'ROOT', n))):
        out[parent] = (out.get(parent, 0) + out.get(child, 0)
                       + G.get_edge_data(parent, child)['weight']
                      )
```

Output:

```
{'Grandchild_1': 4,
 'Child_1': 7,
 'ROOT': 75,
 'Grandchild_0': 1,
 'Child_0': 2,
 'Grandchild_4': 13,
 'Child_4': 22,
 'Grandchild_2': 7,
 'Child_2': 12,
 'Grandchild_3': 10,
 'Child_3': 17}
```

Comment: hey I noticed that this will not work if you add branches to the tree, which I maybe should have added in the example. This is because it will double count certain nodes because the two paths can have the same intermediate node.

Comment: It would be interesting to update your example. I indeed assumed a graph like yours. However this should be easy to handle.

Comment: I am not at home at the moment, will make an example when I am back home

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added an example which highlights the issue